# Remove current year from drop down menu if today is the last day of the fiscal year

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have a jsp page that gives user an option to choose the expiration year for the funding. It basically gives them year and passes that fiscal year to java bean, i.e.:

```
<TR>
  <TD colspan=3>
      <FONT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt" face="trebuchet, verdana, tahoma, sans serif" color=black><B>Funding Expiration Year</B></FONT>
  </TD>
  <TD width="60%">    
       <select id="selectYearId" name="fundExpirationDate">
           <option value=""></option>
           <option value="20150930">2015</option>
           <option value="20160930">2016</option>
           <option value="20170930">2017</option>
           <option value="20180930">2018</option>
           <option value="20190930">2019</option>
           <option value="20200930">2020</option>
           <option value="20210930">2021</option>
           <option value="20220930">2022</option>
           <option value="20230930">2023</option>
           <option value="20240930">2024</option>
           <option value="20250930">2025</option>
       </select>
  </TD>
</TR>
```

I also tried doing this printing of the year dynamically in javascript, so I wouldn't have to come next year and remove 2015... but without any luck. (If anyone can guide me on how to do that I would greatly appreciate it.)

Anyways, the fiscal year ends on 09/30.

When this day comes, I need to remove the option for users to be able to select that year.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly:

In your Controller/Servlet (or even in your JSP) set up a model.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

List<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int i = currentYear - 1; i < currentYear + 10; ++ i){
    years.add(i);
}

request.setAttribute("years", years);
```

In your JSP outout the years using JSTL to iterate the collection:

```
<c:forEach items="${years}" var="year"/>
    <option value="${year}0930">${year}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

@AlanHay thanks for your suggestion. You helped me find the solution.

First I set years attribute like Alan suggested, and check if today is the last day of fiscal year, if so, don't display that year in options list
also make the first option blank, in case user doesn't want to select anything and leave it use default value:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int lastYear = currentYear-1;
    int currentMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int currentDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    List<Integer> years = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    years.add(0);

    for(int i = currentYear-1; i < currentYear + 10; ++ i){
        if(!(currentMonth == 9 && currentDay == 30 && i == lastYear))
            years.add(i);
    }
    request.setAttribute("years", years);
```

Then, I display my select element:

```
<TD>
    <select name="expirationDate">
   <%
   String s_year = "";
   for(int m_year : years)
   {
        s_year = m_year + "";
        if(m_year == 0)
           s_year = "";%>
        <option value="<%=s_year%>0930"><%=s_year%></option>
    <%}%>
</TD>
```